# In Rails: how do I create a many-to-many relationship where both models have teh join key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, belongs-to

I have models `A` and `B`. Both have the `magic` column. If a record `a` from `A` and a `b` from `B` have the same `magic`, then they are related. Many records from `A` and `B` may have the same `magic`.

Is there a way to express this `belongs_to_many` sort of thing in my Rails models? How?

Comment: has_many b, through => :magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a high value in following the Rails way, and what you're trying to do isn't the standard way of doing this.

**The Rails Way**: You should create a has-and-belongs-to-many relationship using an intermediate model and table, as described in the Rails Guides website.

**But if you insist...**: Try this:

```
# model_a.rb
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_bs, class_name: 'ModelB',
                      foreign_key: :magic,
                      primary_key: :magic
end

# model_b.rb
class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_as, class_name: 'ModelA',
                      foreign_key: :magic,
                      primary_key: :magic
end
```

I haven't tested this, but I am fairly certain that it would work.

**Final words...** Don't do it! Follow the Rails way. :)

Comment: NEVER! I WILL INSIST!

Comment: Anyway, it worked perfectly! And it isn't even hackish! Thank you!